# No identities were avalible

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

So I was just about to submit my app when I ran in to this problem. I haven't released an app since iOS 4 and I finally got back to it so this was kinda new to me.

[image]

When I hit the Download Identities... button it tries for a few seconds then I get the error:
No identities were available An administrator must request identities before they can be downloaded.

I also check in the Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Details and my signings identity are both valid as seen on the picture below.

[image]

Any Ideas on what I've might've missed? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! The problem was name identifier, in iTunes Connect I'd written com.companyname.appname and in XCode com.companyname.Appname , since It is case sensitive I just had to change it in XCode and the problem was solved :)